# Redirecting to Parent object when saving a related list object

Tags: junction-object

I have a parent object, which is linked to a junction object. In the related list, I can create a new junction object, and when I click save on the junction object, it then displays the details of the junction object. I would like to redirect the user to the parent object though. Is this possible somehow?
Tia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to set the saveUrl or the retUrl to the Id of the object you want the user to return.

1. Is there a saveURL URL parameter set? If so, redirect to that.
2. Is there a retURL URL parameter set? If so, redirect to that.
3. Redirect to /home/home.jsp

You have some options, the first one would be to override the New button just like this [post](http://www.forcetree.com/2013/05/save-button-override-redirect-to-parent.html) illustrates.

The other option is to create a controller extension and have this type of code.

```
public pagereference redirectUrl(){
    pagereference pf= new pagereference('/'+parent.id);
return pf;

<apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!redirectUrl}"/>
```